# Juntar dois dataframes de mesmo nome mantendo todas as colunas

Tags: r, dataframe

Eu tenho dois *data frames* com o mesmo nome nas colunas, exemplo:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Nom1 Nom2   
  15.1 20.3
  45.5 40.1
  32.1 50.2", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "Nom1 Nom2  
  10.1 90.3
  35.5 80.1
  42.1 50.2", header = T)
```

Eu gostaria de unir `df1` e `df2` de forma a obter o seguinte resultado:

```
|   Nom1   |  Nom2    |
| 15.1|10.1| 20.3|90.3|
| 45.5|35.5| 40.1|80.1| 
| 32.1|42.1| 50.2|50.2|
```

eu tentei ja tentei com as funções merge e join mas nenhuma resulta no meu objetivo

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = "row.names")`?

Comment: eu ja tentei dessa forma mas o que acontece é que ele junta o dos dataframes lado a lado. Então fica: nome1 nome 2 nome 1 nome 2, eu precisava que ficasse nome 1 nome 1 nome 2 nome 2

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim:

```
library(magrittr)

merge(df1, df2, by = "row.names") %>% # agrega os dados
  .[-1] %>% # remove a coluna Row.names
  .[sort(colnames(.))] # ordena as colunas

#  Nom1.x Nom1.y Nom2.x Nom2.y
#1   15.1   10.1   20.3   90.3
#2   45.5   35.5   40.1   80.1
#3   32.1   42.1   50.2   50.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `cbind` para colocar os dois data.frames lado a lado e depois ordenar as colunas pelo nome:

```
df1 <- read.table(
  text = "Nom1 Nom2
          15.1 20.3
          45.5 40.1
          32.1 50.2",
  header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(
  text = "Nom1 Nom2
          10.1 90.3
          35.5 80.1
          42.1 50.2",
  header = TRUE)

df3 <- cbind(df1, df2)

df3
#>    Nom1 Nom2 Nom1 Nom2
#> 1: 15.1 20.3 10.1 90.3
#> 2: 45.5 40.1 35.5 80.1
#> 3: 32.1 50.2 42.1 50.2

df3[order(names(df3))]
#>   Nom1 Nom1.1 Nom2 Nom2.1
#> 1 15.1   10.1 20.3   90.3
#> 2 45.5   35.5 40.1   80.1
#> 3 32.1   42.1 50.2   50.2
```

Note que mesmo que o `cbind` mantenha nomes duplicados, ao ordenar eles serão modificados. O mesmo acontecerá se usar qualquer forma de seleção ou indexação, pois não é possível indexar adequadamente nomes duplicados. Por exemplo:

```
names(subset(df3, select = c("Nom1", "Nom1")))
#> [1] "Nom1"   "Nom1.1"

names(df3[, c(1,3)])
#> [1] "Nom1"   "Nom1.1"
```

Se por qualquer motivo realmente precisa que os nomes sejam mantidos duplicados, terá que usar alguma alternativa à data.frames. `data.table` aceita nomes duplicados, mas mesmo nesse caso para reordenar terá que estabelecer manualmente o número das colunas:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df3)

df3[, c(1,3,2,4)]
#>    Nom1 Nom1 Nom2 Nom2
#> 1: 15.1 10.1 20.3 90.3
#> 2: 45.5 35.5 40.1 80.1
#> 3: 32.1 42.1 50.2 50.2
```

Mas ***isso é altamente não recomendado***. Manter nomes duplicados é simplesmente uma prática ruim.

Answer (score -2):

Opa bom dia! Primeiro o que vc quer fazer chama "merge" que seria juntar em ingles os 2 DF

Aqui tem um tutorial em inglês para te ajudar com isso: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/merging-datasets-r

mas creio que seria

```
df3 -> rbind(df1, df2);
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Então, não da certo com o rbind pq ele faz é juntar as colunas verticalmente. Eu precisava que a coluna 1 do df1 ficasse do lado da coluna 1 do df2 e assim sucessivamente.